# Why does my table of contents not appear in my beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, presentations

I copied a `beamer` presentation and made new slides, but when I compile it the table of contents is missing.

I tried copying and pasting the old presentation into mine and it is still missing the table of contents.

Is there any extra build flags I have to add to make this work?

Comment: Based on an actual question I've gotten.

Comment: Where is your code? or at least the bit which is supposed to produce the toc? Without that it is hard to say....

Comment: This question almost gets in the way of questions regarding problems that could create the same symptom.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build the presentation twice to see the table of contents in it.

The first build will generate it based on the content, and the second will put the finished table of contents in your presentation.

Comment: Note that this isn't at beamer-specific, it's true of any LaTeX document. And technically you should run it three times, as the ToC generation on the second pass can mess up page numbers, and the third pass will fix them

Comment: ajray, when you post questions like that, give people a chance to answer. It is a bit weird that you post a question and a minute later post an answer.

Comment: Can you accept your answer so that it isn't an "unanswered" question any more?